# java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to create a file to a (probably) correct directory

Tags: java, path, relative-path, filepath, fileoutputstream

Hi my problem is that when I use this:

```
final File f = newFile(ButtonOneEvent.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
filePath = f.toString() + "/PlayerList.txt"; //Playerlist.txt being the file I want to create, filePath being an empty string.
System.out.println(f);
```

To define the local directory of the class for this:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Start.filePath); //**Reference Point**
if(inputData != null) {     //Ignore the if else statement
    new PrintStream(fout).println("Text Stuff")
} else {
    new PrintStream(fout).println("Text Stuff")
}
fout.close();
```

I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` on the 'reference point' line when I want to create this file, of course its not already there.
This code is activated by a `JButton`.
BTW the `Sytem.out.println(f)` outputs this:

```
*/Users/HillFamily/Library/Application%20Support/Youth%20Digital/Software/Forge/mcp/eclipse/Football%20Card%20Sorter/bin* <- Directory
```

StackTrace: (Sorry its so long!)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/HillFamily/Library/Application%20Support/Youth%20Digital/Software/Forge/mcp/eclipse/Football%20Card%20Sorter/bin/PlayerList.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
    at events.ButtonOneEvent.actionPerformed(ButtonOneEvent.java:33)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: show us the stack-trace!

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be because your `Start.filePath` is either directory (not file), couldn't be created, or simply doesn't exist. Also, the `Start.filePath` is system-dependent and must be compliant with your platform. You need to make sure that this is correct and also the location which you are referring to has got sufficient access rights for write operation. ANother issue, your full path name  how do you know that you are looking into/writing into the correct location? Do some of the directories along the path actually exist?

To start with the fixing operation - you probably need to check if your `System.out.println(Start.filePath)` prints anything meaningful. If you are having issues with spaces and URL encodings (e.g. %20 is a whitespace in ASCII), you need to start thinking about them in your problem context.

As an example (from Windows's perspective), see the following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/myjavaprojects/folder%20with%20a%20space/haha.txt");
         // This is unchecked exception - we have to rethrow/catchprocess it
         BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

         bos.write("Writing to file".getBytes());        
         bos.flush();
         bos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){

            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/myjavaprojects/folder with a space/haha.txt");
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                 bos.write("Writing to file".getBytes());            
                 bos.flush();
                 bos.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a 'cast' to File? Or how else would I write a file named "PlayerList.txt" at Start.filePath directory? What would you suggest?

Comment: @TurtulWarrior     you are having issues with those %20 symbols in the filepath and they are probably not being accepted by `FileOutputStream` constructor.

Comment: Should I do filePath = filePath.replace("%20", File.separator); ?

Comment: @TurtulWarrior      you really need to make sure that your path is valid - if you have written the path wrong - it simply won't work. Also, I tried the path with %20 in it on Windows, and it throws FileNotFoundException - but I don't know if MAC has the same issue. Simply isolate your file location and do a simple `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)` to see if this throws any exception in runtime.

Comment: I think the actual path might not work,  because I moved the folder library around, and I can't find Youth Digital in Application Support.  I'm not sure why the path still shows the original location  of the files. I'll try to find the correct path manually.

Answer (score 0):

First: look of this method 'newFile', maybe yo have to change to a proper File invocation :

File f = new File(mypath+"PlayerList.txt");

Second, try to see if your class member 'filePath' is not been changed (member of Start class).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an OutputStream to write to a File use:
This will also create the File if it doesn't exist.

```
try {
        Path p = Paths.get("demo", "test.txt");
        Files.createDirectories(p.getParent());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(p, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE));
        out.writeBytes("Hello-World!!");
        out.flush();
        out.close();            
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```